# gtk name for [, ] and /

Tags: xfce, gtk, xfce4-terminal

I am trying to change my xfce4 terminal keybindings by editing the accels.scm file.
One of the changes I lines I wrote is `(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/next-tab" "<Alt>]")`. However, this is not working: it seems that gtk needs me to use some name like "RightSquareBracket" or something of the sort instead of simply "]". The same happens with [ and /. I searched for some list with name-key correspondences for gtk without luck.

Do you know where I can find these correspondences? Or at least what are the strings corresponding to [, ] and /?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch `xev`, press the key and use the 2nd value inside the parenthesis in the 3rd line:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    root 0x7b9, subw 0x0, time 18425452, (520,545), root:(522,547),
    state 0x0, keycode 51 (keysym 0x5d, bracketright), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5d) "]"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5d) "]"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

You'll find `bracketleft` and `slash` for the other ones. Thus

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/next-tab" "<Alt>bracketright")
```

A worse alternative is to look into `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h`, where you will find lines such as

```
#define XK_bracketright                  0x005d  /* U+005D RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET */
```

Comment: Still not working, but I believe your answer is correct. (none of the edits I make to accels.scm seem to have an effect, so the problem is not with the naming of the keys)

Comment: @Soap Oh, sorry to hear that. {1} What is the terminal version? I'm testing on 0.8.10. {2} Is the full path `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm`? {3} Did you try to open a new terminal before trying the new binding? {PS} Sorry if any of those questions seem stupid, I just want to rule out some possible reasons.

Comment: 1. I'm using the same version. 2. Yes, that's the full path. 3. I did. Although: it seems that some changes that I did last week are indeed working. Since I only reboot my computer once a week, it may be needing another reboot. I will try it when it is not inconvenient.
{PS} They don't sound stupid to me :)